How to use ctrl and command hot keys for deleting entire lines, words in macbook terminal?
I don't know what this feature is called, but in text editors, word documents, pretty much everywhere you can type text, and even here on stackexchange, I can press command + delete to delete an entire line or ctrl + delete to delete up to some white space or punctuation. I'm not sure what the equivalent keys are on Windows/Linux, but that's what I use on mac.
However, I cannot achieve this behavior in my macbook terminal. When I press delete along with either command or ctrl, it just does normal character by character deletion. How can I enable the same behavior on my macOS?
